# EditText depbackground shadow effect with press event

Tags: android, layout, cardview

[image]

trying to achieve Editext like given screen shot.

i have tried like in xml layout

```
<com.myapp.act.CheckableCardView
                            style="@style/CardViewStyle"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white"
                            app:cardShadowColorEnd="#FFFFFF"
                            app:cardShadowColorStart="@color/bg2"
                            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bg2"
                            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_2dp">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_45dp">


                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/edtenter_email"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/email_lable"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
                                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:textColorHint="@color/loginhint"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12sp"></EditText>

                            </RelativeLayout>


                        </com.myapp.act.CheckableCardView>
```

in `Style.xml`

```
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>

    </style>
```

in `Jave` class

CheckableCardView.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Checkable;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class CheckableCardView extends CardView implements Checkable {
    // Constructors and view initialization
    private boolean isChecked = false;


    View s;


    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public CheckableCardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setCardBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColorStateList(
                        getContext(),
                        R.color.selector_card_view_color
                )
        );


    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        toggle();
        return super.performClick();

    }
    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.isChecked = checked;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }
    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!this.isChecked);
    }


    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
            android.R.attr.state_checked,
    };

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState =
                super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }

        return drawableState;
    }

}
```

any help will appreciate  to complete EditText style like it,Thank you.

Comment: these are the new neumorphism design controls. Do checkout these library it can help you achieve what you want :- https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSAndroidNeumorphicKit

Comment: ok thank let me check it